# How do I make two columns in MS Word appear sequentially one after the other when they are small in size?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I have two paras in Word.
This is how I'd like them to appear, as they do in a general two column document. It does so for columns that are long enough.

```
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para1para1para1para1para1para1
para1para1para1para1para1para1

para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2
```

However when they are smaller, I get this instead

```
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para1para1para1para1para1para1
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para1para1para1para1para1para1
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para1para1para1para1para1para1
para1para1para1para1para1para1        para1para1para1para1para1para1

para2para2para2para2para2para2        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2        para2para2para2para2para2para2
para2para2para2para2para2para2        para2para2para2para2para2para2
```

How do I get the columns in the format I desire?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, maybe because of my version of Word, or because of other formatting in my document or yours. How did you reduce the column size? I did it by gradually increasing the page margins, but at no point did I get your second format.

Comment: In the format you desire, why does it show only 4 lines of para2 before continuing on to the lower section?  Your proposed plan doesn't make much sense that I can envision.  Point #2: You can wrap text around an image.  Wouldn't surprise me at all if you can wrap text around a table.  However, telling Word to put two columns in only the lower part might be harder.  Essentially, you're ending up with a table that is a backwards-L instead of rectangular.  Sometimes, closed source software doesn't provide a desired feature, and adding desired functionality without source code may not be very easy

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be working in a table, rather than two column document.  Try starting with a new document, going to Layout, and choose 2 column. Make sure you aren't using tables.  No matter how short paragraphs are, they will appear in appropriate column.  (Apologies to anyone who is offended by this being an answer rather than in comments.  I don't have sufficient rep to comment.)